# How to get a specific cell range in a loop?

Tags: excel, vba

How would I rewrite this to work correctly for the cell formulas?

```
For lineNum = 1 To UBound(reportArray, 2)
    With scanSheet
        .Cells(baseRow, 1) = reportArray(1, lineNum)
        .Cells(baseRow, 2) = reportArray(2, lineNum)
        .Cells(baseRow, 3).Formula = "=IF(LEN(B&baseRow)>3,TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(B&baseRow),2)),B&baseRow)"
        .Cells(baseRow, 4).Formula = "=IF(LEN(B&baseRow)>3,TRIM(RIGHT(TRIM(B&baseRow),2)),B&baseRow)"
    End With
    baseRow = baseRow + 1
Next lineNum
```

Comment: Do you mean combining `baseRow` with the letter `B` to make a valid cell reference ? If so, the syntax is e.g. `LEN("B"&baseRow)...`

Comment: yeah, but it still gives me error

Comment: Post more of your code so people understand the context. Also post the error and the line it occurs on...

Comment: @Ravi Gowda  try my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your 2 lines of the formulas to the code below (assuming `baseRow` has a value of a number indicating the row number):

```
  .Cells(baseRow, 3).Formula = "=IF(LEN(B" & baseRow & ")>3,TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(B" & baseRow & "),2)),B" & baseRow & ")"
  .Cells(baseRow, 4).Formula = "=IF(LEN(B" & baseRow & ")>3,TRIM(RIGHT(TRIM(B" & baseRow & "),2)),B" & baseRow & ")"
```

**Note**: In the future use a "Help" string.

```
Dim str As String
str = "=IF(LEN(B" & baseRow & ")>3,TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(B" & baseRow & "),2)),B" & baseRow & ")"
Debug.Print str
```

Then, you will get the formula string in the immediate window:

```
=IF(LEN(B2)>3,TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(B2),2)),B2)
```